# mysql inner join table1 and table 2

Tags: php, mysql, join, response

Mysql. Links two table, table1 is WORKERS, table2 is FIRM. 
Table1 about 50,000 records and Table2 about 15,000 records. USE inner join for link table. Not works for unknown input e-mail.
    Me comes offer from a company or from employees with e-mail. I search by the value of e-mail  the Company and its conditions ...
    Find value of requestX, when know  emailW or emailF  (variable "$W_EMAIL" )
    (e-mail post from FIRM or from WORKERS. For some input values - program not responding ..)

**Table_1**

```
id     | emailW
------ | ------

100    | "bbbb@bb.com"
100    | "ccc@bb.com"
100    | "bbbb@bb.com"
```

**Table_2**

```
id     | requestF      | emailF
------ | ------------- | ------
100    | "service xx"  | "aaa@bb.com"
200    | "service xx"  | "bbb1@bb.com"
300    | "service zz"  | "bbb2@bb.com"
```

if find  bbbb@bb.com ... is ok (e-mail exist in WORKERS)
find  aaa@bb.com ... is ok (e-mail exist in FIRM)
if find xxx@yyy.info  ... no response ... no error ..."white screen"!  (if e-mail not exist !)

**My code:**

```
SELECT table1.id,
       table1.emailW, 
       table2.id,
       table2.requestF,
       table2.emailF            
  FROM table1
 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.id
 WHERE table1.emailW='$W_EMAIL'
    OR table2.emailF='$W_EMAIL'
```

Comment: `<blink>`?  This question is an absolute mess and completely unreadable.  We're happy to help, but you have to actually describe the problem.  Randomly banging on the keyboard isn't the same as asking a question.

Comment: @David, you were incredibly gentle.

Comment: My english is not good. Program code is readable, Its works for existing e-mails in table 1 and 2. Not works - no response for e-mail inside table 1,2  - only "white screen".. it is problem. E-mail in table 2 is correct aaa@bb.com ... for id = 100

Comment: @AgroBiz: "White screen" isn't really a useful description of a problem.  You're going to have to determine more specifically what's happening and where/how this is failing.  There's no reason that simply executing a SQL query should produce a "white screen".  (What screen?  What are you even using to execute the query?)  A query will either return a record set of zero or more results or will produce an error message.

Answer (score 0):

```
select case when t.obs > 0 then 'Ok' else 'Not Ok' end as 'OKorNotOk'
from
(
select s.*,count(*) Obs
from
(
SELECT table_1.id,
       table_1.emailW, 
       table_2.id t2id,
       table_2.requestF,
       table_2.emailF            
  FROM table_1
 left join table_2 ON table_1.id = table_2.id
 union 
 SELECT table_1.id,
       table_1.emailW, 
       table_2.id ,
       table_2.requestF,
       table_2.emailF            
  FROM table_1
 right join table_2 ON table_1.id = table_2.id
 ) s
 where s.emailw = 'aaa@bb.com' or s.emailf = 'aaa@bb.com'
 ) t
```

result

```
+-----------+
| OKorNotOk |
+-----------+
| Ok        |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Or

```
select   t.emailtofind,
            s.id,s.requestf, 
            case when s.srce = 't1' then 'y' else '' end as 'ok found in t1',
            case when s.srce = 't2' then 'y' else '' end as 'ok found in t2',
            case when s.email is null then 'Not Found' else 'Ok' end as Message
from
(
select 't1' as srce,t1.ID,'' as requestf , t1.emailw email from table_1 t1
union
select 't2',t2.ID,t2.requestf , t2.emailf from table_2 t2
) s
right join (select cast('aaa@bb.com' as char(20)) as emailtofind) t on t.emailtofind = cast(s.email as char(20))
```

Result

```
+-------------+------+------------+----------------+----------------+---------+
| emailtofind | id   | requestf   | ok found in t1 | ok found in t2 | Message |
+-------------+------+------------+----------------+----------------+---------+
| aaa@bb.com  |  100 | service xx |                | y              | Ok      |
+-------------+------+------------+----------------+----------------+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Unfortunately it is very complicated for me. I don't understand this.  "I'm not sure what exatcly you mean by this"

Comment: For me is important - the result all of 3 variants:  bbbb@bb.com ...  aaa@bb.com ...  xxx@yyy.info  = print: find or no find

Comment: You wish to search for 3 emails in the same query? Where does $W_email  come from?

Comment: You didn't answer my question

Comment: Both queries will do that.

Comment: can I send for you complex example? my e-mail is agro.ost.eu@gmail.com

Comment: Can you post it to SQL fiddle?

Comment: I cannot help you with PHP - you should add a php tag to your query. Sorry.

Comment: It works perfectly:

    SELECT ...
       FROM t1
         LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
           WHERE t1.EMAIL='aaa@bb.com' OR t2.EMAIL='aa@bb.com' 
      UNION
     SELECT ...
         FROM t1
          RIGHT JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
            WHERE t1.EMAIL='aaa@bb.com' OR t2.EMAIL='aa@bb.com' 

not the same?

    SELECT ...
       FROM t1
         JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
           WHERE t1.EMAIL='aaa@bb.com' OR t2.EMAIL='aa@bb.com' 

What is the difference?

Comment: A join (or Inner Join) joins the left table to right table where the on clause is true for BOTH tables (as modified by the where clause). A left join (or Left Outer Join) joins the left to right table where the on clause is true for BOTH tables AND from the left table even if the on clause evaluates to false (as modified by the where clause). A right join (or right outer join) looks at the tables from right to left. The union statement has an implicit DISTINCT clause which effectively deduplicates.